# Free Order of Rules in Xtext

Tags: xtext

Is it possible to implement free order of rules in xtext? i.e.:

```
A: b=B c=C;
```

must process both

```
B C
```

and

```
C B
```

B and C are really complex rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the concept for that is called unordered groups and can be found in the documentation

```
A: b=B & c=C;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. But I would use it very careful! These unordered groups result in a large decision tree for the parser. For n members of an unordered group your parser implement 2^n possible ways to parse it.

In my opinion it is better to introduce an abstract super rule in the grammar:

```
UnorderedElements:
    A | B | C | D ...;

A:
    ...;
```

And then implement a list instead of an unordered group:

```
ModifiedUnorderedGroup:
    elements+=UnorderedGroup*;
```

Then, it would be possible to have each element more then one time in this list, but you can forbid this by implementing validation rules for each element like this:

```
@Check
def checkA(A a) {
    dar cnt = 0
    (a.eContainer as ModifiedUnorderedGroup).elements.forEach [ el |
        if (el.class == a.class) {
            cnt++
        }
    ]
    if (cnt > 1) {
        error('Elements of type A are allowed only once.', MyDskPackage.eINSTANCE.a_IdAddtribute)
    }
}
```